# How to measure redundancy in code bases?

Tags: architecture, software-design, redundancy, entropy

I inherited a medium-sized code base, whose only programming paradigm appears to have been *Copy&Paste*. There are literally dozens of code snippets that could be easily parametrized and replaced by a simple function call. The code isn't mission-critical, as it's "only" testing code. Nevertheless this makes it a pain to incorporate changes.

- Are there any metrics (in research) that measure the amount of redundancy?
- How could one go about to calculate their values?

Naïve approaches that come to mind:

- See how well the code can be compressed (zipped).
- Pairwise `diff` all files and count equal or similar lines. Similar as in: only one word differs.

Comment: What programming language is it? InteljIdea has some nice code duplication detection (php/java/javascript). "Logic duplication" can probably only be spotted by human eyes

Comment: It's VBScript, so I might be at a loss...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is **clone detection** which is an established research area and there are a number of tools available to detect clones in you code.

The central metric used to quantify the amount of redundancy in the code is called **clone coverage**. It measures the percentage of your code lines that belong to a redundant part. It can be interpreted as the probability that when you change a randomly chosen piece of code, that the change has to be performed at another location as well.

Tools that can detect clones and calculate the clone coverage are, for example, [Teamscale](http://teamscale.eu) and [ConQAT](http://conqat.org). You find an introduction to code clones and clone detection [here](https://www.cqse.eu/en/blog/practical-guide-to-code-clones-part1/).